# Does "propose" mean "suggest" or "intend" in the sentence below?

Tags: vocabulary

Matt: it hit me, she was the one for me, I decided I should either marry her or stop seeing her.

Mike: Wow

Matt: Really, and since I've **proposed** everything has been perfect, I feel like a million bucks. it was the right decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **propose** is given by the [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/propose) thus

> **propose**
>   VERB
>
> **2** Make an offer of marriage to someone.
>    *I have already proposed to Sarah*

So your sentence

> Really, and since I've **proposed** everything has been perfect, I feel like a million bucks.

means

> I am serious, and now I have I asked her to marry me everthing has been perfect, I feel great.